# How can I connect a Raspberry pi 4 running Ubuntu Server to a laptop?

Tags: server, ssh, raspberrypi

I am getting a Raspberry Pi 4. I want it  to connect to my laptop wirelessly, without needing a hdmi cable, display or ethernet cable. I found a tutorial [here](https://www.google.com/amp/s/beebom.com/how-setup-raspberry-pi-without-monitor-ethernet-cable/amp/) that satisfies this, but it uses Raspbian rather than Ubuntu server, which is what I would like to install on it.
Would this tutorial apply on Ubuntu server as well, or is there any other way to do this using Ubuntu Server?

Comment: There isn't much difference between Ubuntu and Raspberry PI OS (The Distro changed its name) its down to core packages.  There are very few packages not available to both distros.   The largest difference is that RPIOS only officially supports 32bit CPU's.   Which means its much slower than 64bit if your using a 64 bit CPU with a RPI4 or CM4 module

Comment: @user535733 Oh thanks a lot! I spent ages googling it, but didn't look on the actual ubuntu website! Please make your comment an answer, so I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the Ubuntu tutorials instead:

http://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-your-raspberry-pi

It includes a method of headless install.

[image]